# passing the value one html page to another html javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass the value one html page to another html javascript function using javascript code. How to pass value. Thanks in advance

```
view.cshtml:
b.on('click', function () {
    document.location.href =  + '?Id=' + sData; // need to pass the value
});

index.cshtml:
function getId(data) { // i need to get the data here
}
```

Comment: please post some code and detail what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: use query string to pass, its simple way of passing value from one html page to another html page

Comment: There are Many solutions starting from **cookies** to **websql** (to name a few[two;-)]), what is the platform and the restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

- Save the data at the client, such as in a cookie.
- Pass it to the service in a GET or POST request, and get the server side script (for example PHP) to pass the value in.

Through the server, if using PHP for example:

```
view.cshtml:
// assume sData = 5
b.on('click', function () {
    document.location.href =  + 'index.php?Id=' + sData;
});
```

When you click the function is triggered it requests index.php from the server.

```
index.php:
<?php
    ...
    echo "var id = $_POST['Id'];";
    echo "function getId() {";
    // Function code here refering to id variable
    echo "}";
    ...
?>
```

index.php generates:

```
index.cshtml:
var id = 5;
function getId() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the GET data via Javascript.
I've created an example which uses a PHP style syntax:

```
<script>
var $_GET = {};
(function() {
    var params=top.location.search.split("?").join("").split("&");
    for(var i=0;i<params.length;i++){
        var param=params[i].split("=");
        $_GET[param[0]]=param[1];
    }
})();

alert($_GET['Id']);

</script>
```

Comment: Based on your code example, I would put it somewhere above the 'getId' function (without the <script> tags).